# Stackoverflow Flair Facebook app error

Tags: support, stack-overflow, facebook

Just to let you know, this happened when I allowed the app in FB:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookRestClientException' with message 'Param assoc_time must be a number' in /home/content/r/e/j/rejun2000/html/fb_so/php/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php:2878 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/r/e/j/rejun2000/html/fb_so/php/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php(2544): FacebookRestClient->call_method('facebook.data.s...', Array) #1 /home/content/r/e/j/rejun2000/html/fb_so/utils.php(188): FacebookRestClient->data_setAssociation('uid_so_uid2', '616867493', '5004213880486') #2 /home/content/r/e/j/rejun2000/html/fb_so/utils.php(208): setSoUID('616867493', -1, Object(Facebook)) #3 /home/content/r/e/j/rejun2000/html/fb_so/index.php(26): updateProfileBox('616867493', -1, Object(Facebook)) #4 {main} thrown in /home/content/r/e/j/rejun2000/html/fb_so/php/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php on line 2878

Answer (score 3):

This isn't our app, we have nothing to do with it, so you'll have to follow up with the developer.

Comment: does exists a certified app to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know this is a FB internal error on the actally site and as @Jeff said SO does not run that app.